# What are the best practices of iPAD GUI development

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios

I am developing my first iPad app. Please suggest me, What are the best practices of iPad GUI development?

Application is almost close to youtube app. There are sign in, sign up view, videos and video with player view. Also have multiple videos listing view with some changes.

**I have navigation bar with multiple buttons.**

**I need to use video player with some custom button.**

I am confuse either I need to create each view for each prototype or one view for multiple types. What are most common mistakes that I need to avoid.

Comment: Hi Adil. As asked I think this question is too vague. What kind of app? What problems do you anticipate? etc...

Comment: Hi Thanks for comment, I just add some more description.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to all Apple have to say on the subject.  It's long.  read it all.

[Apple's iOS human interface guidelines.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)